# Jump between dynamic textfield

Tags: java, javascript, iterator, textfield, struts-tags

I want to jump between textfields, but these fields are generated dynamically through an iterator from struts-tags:

```
<s:iterator value="aList">
 <td width="50px" align="center">
  <s:textfield name="solField" size="2" maxlength="1" style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center"/>                    
 </td>
</s:iterator>
```

I tried jumping with javascript but having the same field name is not working properly.
The code in the browser is (with three items in the list to iterate):

```
<td width="50px" align="center">
 <input type="text" name="solField" size="2" maxlength="1" value="" id="correct_solField" style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center"/>
</td>
<td width="50px" align="center">
 <input type="text" name="solField" size="2" maxlength="1" value="" id="correct_solField" style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center"/>
</td>
<td width="50px" align="center">
 <input type="text" name="solField" size="2" maxlength="1" value="" id="correct_solField" style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center"/>
</td>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Give then the same class instead of name and use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? (using jQuery)

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(){
   if($(this).val().length >= $(this).attr('maxlength'))
   {
       $(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
       // OR even
       // $(this).next('input').focus();
   }
});
```

Is that what you're looking for? http://fiddle.jshell.net/C3jeY/